# sculpt tool is stuck to z axis

Tags: sculpting

I have a student working on a sculpt and i'm not sure how they locked the tool to the z axis[image]

I can't unlock it or change it's axis to anything else

Comment: the problem may be that you have scaled your object on Z, to fix that apply the scale (Ctrl A > Scale) in Object mode, if it doesn't fix please share the file

Comment: That was it.  Applying scale fixed the problem.   Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have scaled your object on Z, to fix that apply the scale (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Scale*) in *Object* mode.